# Ignite cluster active event

Tags: ignite

Is there a way to get notified through a listener when the Ignite cluster gets activated/deactivated? Maybe I'm blind but I can't seem to find this event.

On node #2 I would like to be notified when on node #1 the cluster is activated.

Comment: I don't think there is any event for this, but what exactly are you trying to achieve? Note that activation is a cluster wide operation, so there is no notion of activating on a particular node only.

Comment: As soon as the cluster goes active I want to check what caches are available. On the frontend node I'm displaying cluster details like number of nodes, cluster active status and available caches. When nodes connect/disconnect my listener is called and I update the GUI. But nothing happens when the cluster becomes active.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no specific event for cluster activation/deactivation. I would just send a custom message from the node that did the activation to GUI: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/messaging

Comment: OK, thank you for this hint. Yes, I will use custom message for this. However, I wonder if my use case is so unusual? There are events for all different kind of nodes changes and so many other events but not the main cluster change when it goes to active? Maybe the way I'm using the cluster is not right? Isn't this the suggested way of synchronizing all nodes up running with persistent caches, then activate the cluster which shall trigger the task distribution server node to start?

Comment: Nothing unusual, just relatively new functionality, so missing some minor parts. Having events for this makes sense, I created a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7179

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!